# Get the value stored in the Directive to my Component

Tags: angular, components, angular-directive

I have a requirement of using a directive on an element for storing some data into it. In some components i have to use same directive multiple times on multiple elements. Now, how can I get all the directives data as array of JSONs in a component

Directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[viewmode]"
})
export class ViewModeDirective {

  @Input("viewmode") 
  viewmode: any;
  text: string;

  constructor(
    private elementref: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @HostListener("change", ["$event"])
  onChange(event) {
    if (event.target.id) {
      this.text= $("#" + event.target.id).find('option:selected').text();
    }
  }
}
```

component.html

```html
<select name="senderid" [(ngModel)]="params.senderid" #senderid="ngModel [viewmode]="'senderid'">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let dest of numbers">
    <option [value]="dest.value">{{dest.name}}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

Now, how can I get all the directives data as array of JSONs in a component

Comment: [`@ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) decorator is made for that.

Comment: Thanks for that.. Can I get more explanation